# Need to update one column for records where another value is duplicative in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I am VERY rusty with my SQL, it's been a few years, but I need to write a query to fix something in a table I have.

There are erroneous duplicates where not every column is the same, but I know at least one is.

So I have this query that works:

```
SELECT 
    [IntMsgID], [SortDate], COUNT(*)
FROM 
    [databasename].[dbo].[tblDoc]
GROUP BY
    [IntMsgID], [SortDate]
HAVING 
    COUNT(*) >= 2 
    AND [IntMsgID] IS NOT NULL
```

It identifies the documents in question. What I need to do, then, is take the results from that and update another field simply with the value of Y or 1.

I've done searching and it seems any query I've tried to plug in fails, such as

```
UPDATE [databasename].[dbo].[tblDoc] AS t 
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT [IntMsgID] msgid 
     FROM [databasename].[dbo].[tblDoc] 
     GROUP BY [IntMsgID]) t1 ON t.[IntMsgID] = t1.[IntMsgID]
SET [JG_SQLDupe] = 'Y'
```

I get syntax errors at "AS" and "INNER" and "t1"

Comment: Thanks, I'll look through that thread.  I had not found it on my own searching

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a CTE to achieve this:

```
;with updts as (SELECT [IntMsgID], [SortDate], count(*)
                FROM [databasename].[dbo].[tblDoc]
                Group By [IntMsgID], [SortDate]
                HAVING count(*) >= 2 AND [IntMsgID] is not null)
 update t
 set t.Flag = 'Y' 
 from [databasename].[dbo].[tblDoc] t inner join 
      updts u on t.[IntMsgID] = u.[IntMsgID] 
             and t.[SortDate] = u.[SortDate]
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have been clear, either just Y or 1 exclusively, there no reason I'd need both to ever show up.  So we'll just say I only need the value Y to show up in my JG_SQLDupe field

Comment: See update... "set t.Flag = 'Y' "

Comment: Yeah, made that one change and it's working.  Thanks so much.  Also I had to give aliases to the columns in the initial SELECT statement as it was throwing me an error for the first "updts" value without doing so

Comment: Awesome! If it helped, feel free to accept it as the answer.